# Is string::iterator necessarily a random_access_iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

[This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/begin/) page states that `string::iterator` and `string::const_iterator` are "compiler specific iterator types." Does this mean that that `string::iterator` made be in a category other than `random_access_iterator`?

Comment: [This *better* reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) says otherwise (and is correct).

Comment: I think that this is a reasonable question.  Although cplusplus.com is known to contain many errors, it doesn't mean that this question is bad.  It's just asking for a clarification given incorrect information.

Comment: What misinformation?  Perhaps missing information, but it's not misinformation.  It doesn't say "compiler specific iterator category", it says "compiler specific iterator types", which is correct (or close enough, perhaps it should use the word implementation rather than compiler, but that's a bit of nit-picking)

Comment: Why the down votes? cplusplus.com is very popular - always the top return on Google. If it's incorrect, that's not my fault.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod, Well now you know which one to look for. Personally, I do most of my searching right on a bookmarked http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp now.

Comment: Benjamin is right, you misread the quote. It does not say that they are a different specific category, but rather that the actual C++ type is implementation specific. That is, in some implementation it could be a plain `char*`, while in others it could be a real class holding enough data to do the processing...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ISO C++03, `21.3-2` states:

> (...)Additionally, because the iterators supported by basic_string are
>   **random access iterators**(...)

So yes, those are necessarily random access iterators.

Comment: Guess what's even more trustworthy than cppreference.com :p

Comment: Thanks. Sec 21.4.3 of C++11 states that the "iterators supported by basic_string are random access iterators."

Answer (score 5):

Looking at N3376 `21.4/3`

> The iterators supported by basic_string are random-access iterators.

For such tasks its always a good idea to have a standard (or draft) at hand. It takes a while to get used to looking up things there, but it is the first hand resource.

Answer (score 3):

[This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) says `std::string::iterator` is a `RandomAccessIterator`, and is a lot more trustworthy than cplusplus.com.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't mean it's not a random access iterator (as other answers have said, the standard requires it to be a random access iterator.)

What it means is the exact iterator types are unspecified, i.e. they could be `char*` or they could be `std::string::__iterator` or `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char, std::string>` or something else.  Any of those implementation choices is allowed, as long as it meets the requirements of a random access iterator and can be referred to by the name `string::iterator`